# Mantener una fila selecciona en un DataGridView al actualizar

Tags: c#

Quisiera saber en que método debo usar en mi código para que al momento que se actualiza un DataGridView se mantenga la ultima fila seleccionada. 
Este es el codigo donde actualizo el dgv

Aqui Consulto y refresco el dgv

```
    public void BuscarVisitas(DataGridView dgv, string clave)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conexion = Base.ObtnerCOnexion())
        {

            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT * FROM Visitas WHERE Vendedor ='" + clave + "'"), conexion);
            SqlDataReader leer = com.ExecuteReader();
            int selectedIndex;
            dgv.Rows.Clear();
            dgv.Refresh();

             }
   }
```

Aqui uso un evento para cuando cierre mi form se haga la actualizacion de datos

```
  public void NuevaVisita_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {


        if (txtVendedor.Text == "ADM")
        {
            bs.ADMBuscarVisitas2(dgvVisitas);
            this.tsAutorizar.Enabled = true;

        }
        else
        {
            bs.BuscarVisitas(dgvVisitas, txtVendedor.Text);
            this.tsAutorizar.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: y cual es la fila que queres mantener seleccionada?? y si eso esta sobre el evento close, que fila va a mantener???

Comment: Seria la ultima fila seleccionada por el usuario

Comment: a ver.. podes explicar un poco la logica de esos dos procesos? el orden en que se ejecutan y todo eso?

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas una variable donde guardes la fila seleccionada por el usuario. Antes de actualizar los datos guardas la fila que está seleccioanda, y justo después de haber actualizado el grid con los datos, vuelves a seleccionar la fila que guardaste en la variable.

Por ejemplo, declaras la variable en la clase que representa tu formulario:

```
private int selectedRow = -1; // la inicializamos con -1 porque aun no hay fila seleccionada
```

Luego, antes de cargar los datos desde la bdd y alimentar al grid con ellos, guardas la fila seleccionada:

```
public void BuscarVisitas(DataGridView dgv, string clave)
{
    if (dgv.SelectedRows.Count > 0) selectedRows = dgv.SelectedRows[0].Index;
    using (SqlConnection conexion = Base.ObtnerCOnexion())
    {
```

Y después de actualizar regresas la selección (supongo que le faltan líneas de código al método BuscarVisitas que pusiste):

```
        dgv.Rows.Clear();
        dgv.Refresh();

         }
    if (selectedRows >=0) dgv.Rows[selectedRows].Selected = true;
}
```

Eso si, faltaría validar por ejemplo, que después de la consulta y que se rellene el grid, efectivamente hay datos en el grid. Supongo que ya has configurado tu grid para que no acepte selección múltiple, y que se seleccione toda la fila y no celdas individuales.

EDIT: Veo que lo que buscas es que la última fila es la que debe permanecer seleccionada, si esto es así, no es necesario guardar la fila que está seleccionada antes de rellenar el grid, depende de cómo llenes el grid, si por medio de daatasource o manualmente agregando filas. Si lo haces  usando la propiedad datasource, hay un evento llamado databindingcomplete donde puedes ya seleccionar la última fila. Si lo haces manual agregando filas, seleccionas la última al finalizar de agregar datos.

Ejemplo usando el evento databindingcomplete:

```
private void dgv_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    var lastRow = gdv.Rows.Count - 1;
    if (lastRow >= 0)
        dgv.Rows[lastRow].Selected = true;
}
```

Comment: Una cosa, si guardas el id de la fila seleccionada y actualizas el grid, no es posible que al refrescar, las filas tengan otro orden y la que tenía el indice que has guardado sea otra? no sería mejor guardar la fila completa y al recargar el grid, recorrer sus filas hasta encontrar la guardada?

Comment: Así es, de hecho comenté que faltan validaciones, no solo si están en otro orden, sino que puede ser que no sea el mismo número de datos. Es mas o menos la idea de lo que tiene que hacer.

Comment: No entiendo porqué el voto negativo.

Comment: Porque no le resuelves la duda, das una idea, la cual me parece correcta pero no resuelves el problema del usuario

Comment: Parece que ya medio lo resolví estoy guardando el ultimo valor en una variable y después uso un foreach para comprobar que el valor que almacenen en la variable se encuentre dentro del datagridview por el momento asi me esta funcionando pero tiene un error el cual se mantiene la ultima fila seleccionada pero al hacer el refresh el index se va a la primera fila pero mantiene la ultima fila seleccionada por el usuario. gracias por la ayuda